# How to calculate per-page STD in matlab?

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

Suppose I have matrix `A` of 100x200x300. Third dimension is called "page" in Matlab and this matrix has 300 pages then.

Now I want to calculate standard deviation within each page and get a result matrix of 1x1x300.

I can't just do

```
std(std(A,0,1),0,2)
```

because normalization will be wrong as I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to collapse the first two dimensions into one (i.e. into columns) using [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html); and then compute [`std`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/std.html) along each column:

```
Ar = reshape(A, size(A,1)*size(A,2), size(A,3));
result = std(Ar);
```

This will give you a 1x300 vector as result. If you really need it to be 1x1x300, use

```
result = shiftdim(result, -1);
```

Comment: As a short-cut you can always do `Ar = reshape(A, [], size(A,3));`